# How do you apply the 4th order Runge Kutta method of numerical integration to the problem of projectile motion through atmosphere?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

How do you apply the 4th order Runge Kutta method of numerical integration to the problem of projectile motion through atmosphere?

Comment: 1. Write a problem statement.  2. State assumptions, propose a numerical model with proper initial conditions, which allows you to obtain some ordinary differential equation, and eventually arrive at a relation between $\ddot x$ (acceleration) and time $t$.  3. Discretize the time domain into small chunks.  4. Apply RK4 to $\ddot x$ to obtain $\dot x$ (velocity) at any timestep.  5. In the same timestep, again, apply RK4 to $\dot x$ to obtain $x$.

Comment: About the application of RK4, you could consult [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_method), but it will take a while to figure out what's going on.